# Python 3.6 Requests SSLerror "unexpected eof while reading'

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

the following code works perfectly fine under Python 2.7:

```
import requests
url = "https://ec.europa.eu/clima/ets/"
r = requests.get(url)
r.status_code
```

However under Python 3.6 or 3.7 the code breaks with the error message:

> SSLError: ("read error: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_read_n', 'unexpected eof while reading')],)",)

Would be very thankful for every suggestion how to run it under Python 3.

P.S. requests version is 2.22 under all python versions

**Update**

It seems that the error was caused by openssl version 1.1.1e. Upgrading to 1.1.1f solved the problem for me.

Comment: Hi Jan,
I test your code with Python 3.6, and it work perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for testing. Is it the same requests version?

Comment: Nop, i use requests.__version__ == '2.23.0'

Comment: i setup clean Python 3.6 environment and only install requests version 2.23. Still get the same error. Very strange. Think I need to fall back to 2.7 for the moment. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you behind a proxy ?

Comment: Same issue with oauth2.py (google auth). I'm assuming it's related to this (openssl-1.1.1e): https://github.com/openssl/openssl/pull/11400 Did you recently upgrade openssl?

Comment: Yes, I recently re-installed my anaconda distribution. Concerning the proxy, I don't use one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be related to openssl 1.1.1e bug

You it is your server check version that you have

```
yum info ea-openssl11
```

If you have 1.1.1e, then you can downgrade to 1.1.1d

```
yum downgrade ea-openssl11
```

and restart php-fpm if you have it

Comment: You are right. It seems the bug was removed in 1.1.1f. Thanks!